# Expansion of imaginary numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

If $(1+i)^{100}$ is expanded, what is the value of the real part of the result? I know that this has to do with binomial theory and Pascal's triangle, but I don't know how to use it here.

Comment: Let me know how I can improve my answer.  I just want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of expanding the term $1+i$, let's write it in polar for as $2^{1/2}e^{i\pi/4}$.

Then, we have

$$(1+i)^{100}=2^{50}e^{i25\pi}=-2^{50}$$

Comment: @MartinArgerami Yes.  I've edited.

Comment: Oh, thanks! I didn't know that _e_ can be substituted like that.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint: Do not Expand**

$$1+i=\sqrt2\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}+\frac{i}{\sqrt2}\right)=\sqrt2\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{4}+i\sin\frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$
Now using 
[De Moivre's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula)
 we have

$$(\cos x + i\sin x )^n=\cos nx + i\sin nx $$